# China Permanent residence expiration

Tags: resident-permit, china

Please how many days can I be allowed to stay in china after my resident permit expires, can I stay 5 more days

Comment: Hi, in order for someone who knows something about Chinese resident permits to help, can you please clarify what kind of resident permit do you hold? The question title 'China permanent residence expiration' sounds contradictory itself.

Comment: there is a Permanent Resident card, so it's not necessarily a typo.  But I doubt it matters for the answer.  They are very concerned with regulating coming and going

Answer (score 1):

The short answer with China is no, you can't overstay without penalty.
I don't know exactly what the typical penalty is for 5 days, or if it is different for your permit type.

- But no, they don't generally have any "free" or "grace period" on visa dates.

At best you'll have a lot of hassle when you exit and pay a fine before you can go.  At worst you might be jailed for some days and blacklisted for some years.

For a more official statement rather than just my word for it, [here is the US State Department page on travel to China](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/China.html).  Go down to the section "Entry, Exit and Visa Requirements".  And here is [another State Department page with more details on the same](https://china.usembassy-china.org.cn/u-s-citizen-services/local-resources-of-u-s-citizens/information-chinese-visas/).

- If you know you want a short extension for a specific reason, go to the police office that issued the permit and request the extension.

If it is requested far in advance, for a very short length, and for a specific event you can show evidence for, they might well give it to you.

Comment: Do you have an official source for your answer?

Comment: I can find something appropriate... just a minute;  if you search this online, you can see very broad consensus as well

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the proper procedures as you should your work visa will be converted to a 30 day tourist visa to allow you to sort your affairs and close bank accounts etc after you finish your work contract, if however you didn’t follow the company exit procedure when you stopped working and have been in china on that permanent residence card but not employed you have committed a crime in China and depending on how you handle this can be deported and some times worse, few people realize or understand how important it is to follow proper entry and exit procedures in china